# Powershell Regex to match specific order of text and include only them in results

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to find working regex for powershell in Select-String Commandlet looking for specific text which is marked as start of the looking text and from this point look for other specific texts until last text is found.

Example of a file with text:

```
[Begin Of_Header]
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
Serial=0X94PA
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
Timer=0
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
Tag.SM=00
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
Tag.OM=00
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
Tag.UC=00
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
Events=pd_exf1
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
Acp="My looking dynamic text"
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
Dir=6
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
WG=100
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
H=95.5
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"

[Begin Of_Header]
Serial=0XZZZ
Timer=0
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
Tag.OM=00
Tag.UC=00
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
Events=pd_exf1
Acp="My looking dynamic text"
Dir=6
WG=100
H=95.5


[Begin Of_Header]
Serial=0XPPPP
Timer=0
Tag.SM=00
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
Tag.OM=00
Tag.UC=00
Some.Text="Text"
Some.Text="Text"
Events=pd_exf1
Acp="My looking dynamic text"
Dir=6
WG=100
H=95.5
```

In this case it should look for static word **[Begin Of_Header]**, from this point start exact order match of dynamic values beginning with **Serial=** and ending with **Acp="My looking dynamic text"**. And the Acp= can have various values + serial. If there is missing value, for example **Tag.SM=00** is missing, then skip searching in this group and jump to next **[Begin Of_Header]** and start analyzing again.

The result should be like this:

```
[Begin Of_Header]
Serial=0X94PA
Timer=0
Tag.SM=00
Tag.OM=00
Tag.UC=00
Events=pd_exf1
Acp="My looking dynamic text"

[Begin Of_Header]
Serial=0XPPPP
Timer=0
Tag.SM=00
Tag.OM=00
Tag.UC=00
Events=pd_exf1
Acp="My looking dynamic text"
```

I found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37178832/2252286) but doesn't work exactly as I want.

Also this don't work as expected because it does not exclude broken exact match order:

```
Select-String -LiteralPath "C:\myfile.txt" -Pattern "\[Begin Of_Header\]|Serial=|Timer=|Tag.SM=|Tag.OM=|Tag.UC=|Events=|Acp=" | Select-Object LineNumber,Line
```

Comment: Easier, cleaner and more maintainable to implement that with a simple state machine. Regular expressions are for recognizing words, not structures.

Comment: Seems like a most suitable solution. Thanks for advice David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Regular expression is complex but since the order of the elements is fixed I don't see a problem.

---

```
$Header = '[Begin Of_Header]'
$RE = [RegEx]'(?smi)(^Serial=.*?$).*(^Timer=.+?$).*(^Tag\.SM=.+?$).*(^Tag\.OM=.+?$).*(^Tag\.UC=.+?$).*(^Events=.+?$).*(^Acp=.+?$)'

(Get-Content .\myfile.txt -raw) -split [RegEx]::Escape($Header)|
    Select-String $RE | ForEach-Object{
        $Header
        for($i=1;$i -lt 8;$i++){$_.matches.groups[$i].value}
        ""
    }
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2017\09\10\SO_46139332.ps1
[Begin Of_Header]
Serial=0X94PA
Timer=0
Tag.SM=00
Tag.OM=00
Tag.UC=00
Events=pd_exf1
Acp="My looking dynamic text"

[Begin Of_Header]
Serial=0XPPPP
Timer=0
Tag.SM=00
Tag.OM=00
Tag.UC=00
Events=pd_exf1
Acp="My looking dynamic text"
```

---

- The Header is used to split file contents into chunks to match the RE separately
- `(?smi)` advises the RE to use

  - s modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters
  - m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
  - i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match
- `(^Serial=.*?$).*`

  - 1st Capturing Group (^Serial=.*?$)
    ^ asserts position at start of a line
    Serial= matches the characters Serial= literally (case insensitive)
    .*?
    . matches any character 
    *? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
    $ asserts position at the end of a line
    .*
    matches any character 
    * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks! I did it different way but yours cleaner and faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to try something else other than regex. I would just create an array with some `if` conditions and grab what I need.

Something like this....

not sure if this is the most code efficient but it works..

```
$content = get-content "C:\myfile.txt"

$serial = @()
$timer = @()
$sm = @()
$om = @()
$uc = @()
$events = @()
$acp = @()

Foreach($line in $content){
    If ($line -match "Serial="){$serial += $line}
    If ($line -match "Timer="){$timer += $line}
    If ($line -match "Tag.SM="){$sm += $line}
    If ($line -match "Tag.OM="){$om += $line}
    If ($line -match "Tag.UC="){$uc += $line}
    If ($line -match "Events="){$events += $line}
    If ($line -match "Acp="){$acp += $line}
}

"[Begin Of_Header]"
$serial[0]
$timer[0]
$sm[0]
$om[0]
$uc[0]
$events[0]
$acp[0]

"[Begin Of_Header]"
$serial[2]
$timer[2]
$sm[2]
$om[2]
$uc[2]
$events[2]
$acp[2]
```